# Springboot + angular can't load the index html

Tags: html, spring-boot

I'm learning spring boot recently and I use angular as the frontend. I'm tired of the thymeleaf, so I try to load the html5 without the module (I put the html, css and js in the package `resource/static`). I can load the `index.html` only when I enter the specific URL `http://localhost:8080/index.html` instead of the `http://localhost:8080/`.

[image: Here is my project structure]

How can I directly get the index with `http://localhost:8080/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a controller which serves `index.html` on `/`:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "/resources/static/index.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had the @EnableWebMvc tag in a different class and this didn't allow my index.html to be returned from resources/static when accessing localhost:8080

Comment: hi same issue here, may i know how you solve it in 2023 ?